# Session not getting destroyed in internet explorer

Tags: php, session, internet-explorer

I have a `logout.php` file which actually does what it says, logs out the user from the application by destroying the session and redirecting them back to login page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( isset( $_SESSION ) &&
        !empty( $_SESSION ) )
    {
        $con = mysqli_connect( "localhost",
                               "root",
                               "",
                               "ctp" );

        $associate = $_SESSION[ 'user' ];
        date_default_timezone_set( 'Asia/Kolkata' );
        $tn = time();

        $dateTime = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s",
                          $tn );

        $sql = "INSERT INTO ind_ctp_workflow_log
                VALUES ( 'CTPLogoutButton',
                         'CTP - Logout',
                         '$associate',
                         '$dateTime' )";

        mysqli_query( $con,
                      $sql );

        unset( $_SESSION );
        session_destroy();

        header( "Location:index.php?r=site/login" );    
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'There is no active session<br>\n
        echo '<a href = "index.php?r=site/login">\n'
        echo '    Click here\n';
        echo '</a>\n';
        echo 'to login';
    }
?>
```

This works fine in Chrome, but not on IE, The workflow that it follows is:

1) Login page - session not set, so display this page

2) Home page - session set, so stay here, else go to login page

3) Logout page - delete session, go to login page

4) Login page - Session set, go to homepage

Hence I can understand that, session is not getting deleted in IE.  This works fine in Mozilla too,

In Chrome, Mozilla the 4th step changes to

4) Login page - Session not set, stay here

There are very few questions in SO and those are all 4 years ago, and does not have a very convincing answer for my case.

Comment: used this $_SESSION = array();

Comment: Can you post your login page please? You might want to set an index in your session, which you compare against, like $_SESSION('is_logged_in')...

Comment: @chickenchilli the login page is written in yii framework. So it has modules across different pages. and no specific login page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `unset($_SESSION)`, use this:

```
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
```

Comment: This did not work for me, I've replaced it, but the same problem persists

Comment: My only other guess is that IE is caching the page and won't let go of it. After you're tried to log out and it redirects, if you refresh the page does it still show that you're logged in?

Comment: refreshed page after logout,closed and opened tab,restarted IE, restarted system, restarted server too! would it be because the project is built in a framework?

Comment: Do you have server side caching going on? That might be affecting it. Is it also possible that your logout button has something incompatible with IE that's causing it not to fire correctly in the first place?